# MySql If Exists Set Value?

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns a bunch of information and using a join to join two tables and it works perfectly fine.

But I have a field called tickets which I need to see if there is a time available and if there is even one set it to 1 otherwise set it to 0. So like this.

```
SELECT 
name,poster,sid,tickets = (IF SELECT id FROM times WHERE shows.tid=times.tid LIMIT 1, 
if value returned set to 1, otherwise set to 0) 
FROM shows JOIN show_info ON (id) WHERE sid=54 order by name ASC
```

Obviously that is not a correct MySQL statement, but it would give an example of what I am looking for.

Is this possible? Or do I need to do the first select then for a loop through results and do the second select and set value that way? Or is one better performance wise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would look at `EXISTS` it is in most of the cases much faster then to `COUNT` all the items that matches your where statement. With that said. You query should look something like this:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  poster,
  sid,
  (
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM times WHERE shows.tid=times.tid)
      THEN 1 
      ELSE 0
   END 
  )AS tickets 
FROM 
  shows 
  JOIN show_info ON (id) WHERE sid=54 order by name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at CASE statement

```
SELECT name,poster,sid,
Case WHEN (SELECT count(id) FROM times WHERE shows.tid=times.tid) > 0 THEN 1 else 0 END as Tickets
FROM shows 
JOIN show_info ON (id) 
WHERE sid=54 order by name ASC
```

Comment: I was looking for something to return a list with a column that would have an 'X' if a row existed in one of the tables, and a blank if it didn't.  This usage of CASE was what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT 
name,
poster,
sid,
CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM times WHERE shows.tid=times.tid ) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CASE tickets
FROM shows 
JOIN show_info ON (id) 
WHERE sid=54 
order by name ASC
```

For reference on `CASE` see [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case-statement.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do this I can think of:

```
SELECT name, poster, sid,EXISTS(SELECT * times WHERE shows.tid=times.tid) tickets
FROM shows
JOIN show_info USING (id)
WHERE sid = 54
ORDER BY name
```